# Pandas, How to calculate week number of custom block?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    id              Date                Season
0   72845e1328  2014-02-12 00:00:00+00:00   1
1   83734b1c9b  2016-08-30 00:00:00+00:00   3
2   fbdca45588  2017-05-30 00:00:00+00:00   3
3   698a467af4  2019-08-29 00:00:00+00:00   5
4   698a467af4  2019-08-30 00:00:00+00:00   5
...
```

I want to create `week number` basis on Date.

Tricky part is the `week number` will need to start from the first week of each seasons (season 1 to season 5). Also each week starts from Monday to Sunday.

I want to have the final output a below:

```
    id              Date                Season   Week_of_Season
...
0   72845e1328  2019-08-12 00:00:00+00:00   5          1
1   83734b1c9b  2019-08-19 00:00:00+00:00   5          2
2   fbdca45588  2019-08-26 00:00:00+00:00   5          3
3   698a467af4  2019-09-02 00:00:00+00:00   5          4
4   698a467af4  2019-09-09 00:00:00+00:00   5          5
...
```

Comment: Deleted the previous post

Answer (score 1):

Get week of years first by [`Series.dt.weekofyear`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekofyear.html) and then grouping by `Season` with [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

#oldier pandas versions
#df['Week_of_Season'] = df['Date'].dt.weekofyear
df['Week_of_Season'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week

df['Week_of_Season'] = df.groupby('Season')['Week_of_Season'].rank(method='dense')
print (df)
           id                      Date  Season  Week_of_Season
0  72845e1328 2019-08-12 00:00:00+00:00       5               1
1  83734b1c9b 2019-08-19 00:00:00+00:00       5               2
2  fbdca45588 2019-08-26 00:00:00+00:00       5               3
3  698a467af4 2019-09-02 00:00:00+00:00       5               4
4  698a467af4 2019-09-09 00:00:00+00:00       5               5
```